# Spark is sorting already sorted partitions resulting in performance loss

Tags: apache-spark, caching, optimization, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For a cached dataframe, partitioned and sorted within partitions, I get good performance when querying the key with a `where` clause but bad performance when performing a join with a small table on the same key.

See example dataset `dftest` below with 10Kx44K = 438M rows.

```
sqlContext.sql(f'set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions={32}')
sqlContext.clearCache()
sc.setCheckpointDir('/checkpoint/temp')
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

start_date = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)
end_date   = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)

dates = [ start_date + datetime.timedelta(n) for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days))]

dfdates=spark.createDataFrame(list(map(lambda x: Row(date=x), dates))) # some dates
dfrange=spark.createDataFrame(list(map(lambda x: Row(number=x), range(10000)))) # some number range

dfjoin = dfrange.crossJoin(dfdates)
dftest = dfjoin.withColumn("random1", round(rand()*(10-5)+5,0)).withColumn("random2", round(rand()*(10-5)+5,0)).withColumn("random3", round(rand()*(10-5)+5,0)).withColumn("random4", round(rand()*(10-5)+5,0)).withColumn("random5", round(rand()*(10-5)+5,0)).checkpoint()
dftest = dftest.repartition("number").sortWithinPartitions("number", "date").cache()
dftest.count() # 438,290,000 rows
```

The following query now takes roughly a second (on a small cluster with 2 workers):

```
dftest.where("number = 1000 and date = \"2001-04-04\"").count()
```

However, when I write a similar condition as a join, it takes 2 minutes:

```
dfsub = spark.createDataFrame([(10,"1900-01-02",1),
  (1000,"2001-04-04",2),
  (4000,"2002-05-05",3),
  (5000,"1950-06-06",4),
  (9875,"1980-07-07",5)],
["number","date", "dummy"]).repartition("number").sortWithinPartitions("number", "date").cache()
df_result = dftest.join(dfsub, ( dftest.number == dfsub.number ) & ( dftest.date == dfsub.date ), 'inner').cache()
df_result.count() # takes 2 minutes (result = 5)
```

I would have expected this to be roughly equally fast.  Especially since I would hope that the larger dataframe is already clustered and cached.  Looking at the plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
InMemoryTableScan [number#771L, date#769, random1#775, random2#779, random3#784, random4#790, random5#797, number#945L, date#946, dummy#947L]
   +- InMemoryRelation [number#771L, date#769, random1#775, random2#779, random3#784, random4#790, random5#797, number#945L, date#946, dummy#947L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
         +- *(3) SortMergeJoin [number#771L, cast(date#769 as string)], [number#945L, date#946], Inner
            :- *(1) Sort [number#771L ASC NULLS FIRST, cast(date#769 as string) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :  +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(number#771L) && isnotnull(date#769))
            :     +- InMemoryTableScan [number#771L, date#769, random1#775, random2#779, random3#784, random4#790, random5#797], [isnotnull(number#771L), isnotnull(date#769)]
            :           +- InMemoryRelation [number#771L, date#769, random1#775, random2#779, random3#784, random4#790, random5#797], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
            :                 +- Sort [number#771L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#769 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :                    +- Exchange hashpartitioning(number#771L, 32)
            :                       +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[number#771L,date#769,random1#775,random2#779,random3#784,random4#790,random5#797]
            +- *(2) Filter (isnotnull(number#945L) && isnotnull(date#946))
               +- InMemoryTableScan [number#945L, date#946, dummy#947L], [isnotnull(number#945L), isnotnull(date#946)]
                     +- InMemoryRelation [number#945L, date#946, dummy#947L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                           +- Sort [number#945L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#946 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(number#945L, 32)
                                 +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[number#945L,date#946,dummy#947L]
```

A lot of time seems to be spent sorting the larger dataframe by number and date (this line: `Sort [number#771L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#769 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0`). It leaves me with the following questions:

- within the partitions, the sort order for both the left and right side is exactly the same, and optimal for the JOIN clause, why is Spark still sorting the the partitions again?
- as the 5 join records match (up to) 5 partitions, why are all partitions evaluated?
- It seems Catalyst is not using the info of `repartition` and `sortWithinPartitions` of the cached dataframe. Does it make sense to use `sortWithinPartitions` in cases like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer your three questions:

> within the partitions, the sort order for both the left and right side is exactly the same, and optimal for the JOIN clause, why is Spark still sorting the the partitions again?

The sort order in both DataFrames is NOT the same, because of different datatypes in your sorting column `date`, in `dfsub` it is `StringType` and in `dftest` it is `DateType`, therefore during the join Spark sees that the ordering in both branches is different and thus forces the `Sort`.

> as the 5 join records match (up to) 5 partitions, why are all partitions evaluated?

During the query plan processing Spark does not know how many partitions are non-empty in the small DataFrame and thus it has to process all of them.

> It seems Catalyst is not using the info of repartition and sortWithinPartitions of the cached dataframe. Does it make sense to use sortWithinPartitions in cases like these?

Spark optimizer is using the information from `repartition` and `sortWithinPartitions` but there are some caveats about how it works. To fix up your query it is also important to repartition by the same columns (both of them) that you are using in the join (not just one column). In principle this should not be necessary and there is a related [jira](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24087) in progress that is trying to solve that.

So here are my proposed changes to your query:

1. Change the type of `date` column to StringType in `dftest` (Or similarly change to DateType in `dfsub`):

   ```
   dftest.withColumn("date", col("date").cast('string'))
   ```
2. In both DataFrames change

   ```
   .repartition("number")
   ```

   to

   ```
   .repartition("number", "date")
   ```

After these changes you should get a plan like this:

```
*(3) SortMergeJoin [number#1410L, date#1653], [number#1661L, date#1662], Inner
:- Sort [number#1410L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#1653 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(number#1410L, date#1653, 200)
:     +- *(1) Project [number#1410L, cast(date#1408 as string) AS date#1653, random1#1540, random2#1544, random3#1549, random4#1555, random5#1562]
:        +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(number#1410L) && isnotnull(cast(date#1408 as string)))
:           +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[number#1410L,date#1408,random1#1540,random2#1544,random3#1549,random4#1555,random5#1562]
+- Sort [number#1661L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#1662 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(number#1661L, date#1662, 200)
      +- *(2) Filter (isnotnull(number#1661L) && isnotnull(date#1662))
         +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[number#1661L,date#1662,dummy#1663L]
```

so there is only one `Exchange` and one `Sort` in each branch of the plan, both of the are coming from the `repartition` and `sortWithinPartition` that you call in your transformations and the join does not induce any more sorting or shuffling. Also notice that in my plan there is no `InMemoryTableScan`, since i did not use cache.